# Codeigniter structure

Tags: model-view-controller, codeigniter, controller, codeigniter-2, hmvc

I am planning to develop a portal separated into modules using codeigniter's third party HMVC.
One such module is "Classifieds".

I was thinking of the following structure:

`www.site.com/classifieds/2-a-category-name/32-a-listing-title`

This will list the details of the particular listing ID 32 which belongs to category ID 2

`www.site.com/classifieds/4-a-category-name`

This will list all the listings in the category ID 4

`www.site.com/classifieds/add/listing, www.site.com/classifieds/edit/listing/4, www.site.com/classifieds/delete/category/5`

This will add/edit/delete listings and categories.

Now I am confused as to what controllers I should be using? Is it OK to have "Add", "Edit", "Delete" controllers? and use the main "classifieds" controller to display the pages according to the URI segments?

Answer (score 1):

Your URLs should be something like:

```
www.site.com/classifieds/listing/add
www.site.com/classifieds/listing/edit
www.site.com/classifieds/listing/delete
www.site.com/classifieds/category/add
```

With HMVC you can have structures like

```
classified
  controllers
    classified.php
    category.php
    listing.php
```

so for `www.site.com/classifieds/listing/add` you would add a method `add()` to the listing controller in the classified module